# Dynamic height of ListView with a large number of data in Android

Tags: android, listview, dynamic, height

I'm working on a program that shows the image.
[image]

This is a ListView and GridView wrapped in ScrollView.
The program works as follows: when you click on GridView item, selected item is added to the ListView, thus it is possible to add several items into the ListView. Consequently, it is possible to scroll through the entire contents of ScrollView. Everything works fine until ListView contains a large amount of data, in this case adding and rendering of the new ListView will slow down significantly. Therefore, I would like to ask if anyone dealt with similar problem and knows better way to resize and redraw the entire ListView.

Currently I perform the calculation and adjust the size of ListView as follows:

```
public ListUtils(ListView listView){
    ListAdapter adapter = listView.getAdapter();

    int count = adapter.getCount();
    int itemsHeight;    

    View oneChild = listView.getChildAt(0);
    if( oneChild == null){
        return;
    }

    itemsHeight = oneChild.getHeight();

    LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams)listView.getLayoutParams();
    params.height = (itemsHeight * count);
    listView.setLayoutParams(params);
}
```

Comment: Take a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11406856/1919749

Comment: I think a listview itself is scrollable by default. Not sure if the scrollview is necessary, actually... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13679633/how-to-make-android-listview-scrollable

Comment: It is clear to me that the ListView is scrollable but I want to scroll through the ListView and GridView at the same time

Answer (score 1):

If you're having performance issues with the ListView you're using I'd recommend switching to a `RecyclerView` and use a custom `RecyclerView.Adapter`. Take a look [here](https://developer.android.com/training/material/lists-cards.html) and [here](http://www.grokkingandroid.com/first-glance-androids-recyclerview/).