# Make whole layout scrollable and not just listview

Tags: android, listview, scrollable

I am trying to make whole layout scrollable but in this case only listview is being scrolled and not the whole layout. Please tell me how can I make the whole page to be scrolled up and not just the listview in it. Thanks

1. My XML file

   ```
   <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   android:orientation="vertical"
   tools:context=".MainActivity">

   <LinearLayout
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content">

   <GridView
       android:id="@+id/grid"
       android:layout_width="fill_parent"
       android:layout_height="fill_parent"
       android:layout_centerInParent="true"
       android:columnWidth="100dp"
       android:gravity="center"
       android:horizontalSpacing="2dp"
       android:numColumns="auto_fit"
       android:paddingTop="2dp"
       android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
       android:verticalSpacing="2dp" />

   </LinearLayout>

   <TextView
   android:id="@+id/text"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
   android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
   android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
   android:text="More Devices"
   android:textStyle="bold" />

   <ListView
   android:id="@+id/list"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:paddingBottom="3dp"
   android:paddingLeft="3dp"
   android:paddingTop="3dp" />

   </LinearLayout>
   ```
2. My MainActivity.java

package project.example.com.project;

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.GridView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SimpleAdapter;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;


public class MainActivity extends Activity {

GridView grid;
String[] gridtext = {"Text 1", "Text 2", "Text 3", "Text 4", "Text    5", "Text 6", "Text 7", "Text 8", "Text 9"};
int[] gridimage = {R.drawable.img, R.drawable.img, R.drawable.img,   R.drawable.img, R.drawable.img, R.drawable.img, R.drawable.img,   R.drawable.img, R.drawable.img};
ListView listView;
String[] listtext = {"List 1", "List 2", "List 3", "List 4", "List   4", "List 4"};
int[] listimage = {R.drawable.image, R.drawable.image,  R.drawable.image, R.drawable.image, R.drawable.image, R.drawable.image};

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
CustomGrid adapter = new CustomGrid(MainActivity.this, gridtext,  gridimage);
grid = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.grid);
grid.setAdapter(adapter);
grid.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener()    {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                            int position, long id) {
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "You Clicked at " +   gridtext[+position], Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    });

    List<HashMap<String, String>> list = new  ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

    String[] from = {"txt", "img"};
    int[] to = {R.id.list_text, R.id.list_image};
    SimpleAdapter simpleAdapter = new   SimpleAdapter(getBaseContext(), list, R.layout.list_row, from, to);
    for (int i = 0; i < listtext.length; i++) {
    HashMap<String, String> hashMap = new HashMap<String, String> ();
    hashMap.put("txt", listtext[i]);
    hashMap.put("img", Integer.toString(listimage[i]));
    list.add(hashMap);
    }

    listView.setAdapter(simpleAdapter);
    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new  AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int   position, long id) {
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "You Clicked at " +            listtext[+position], Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    });
    View header = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.header,  null);
    listView.addHeaderView(header);


    }
    }
```

Comment: try scrollview .Just google it for examples

Comment: **Avoid like death** putting a scrollable View, such as a ListView or GridView and derivates inside another scrollable View (i.e.: a ScrollView).

Comment: Use a ScrollView and instead of the ListView use a LinearLayout to inflate your rows. Like someone said before me, avoid using a scrollable elements inside other scrollable elements if they scroll in the same orientation. You will run into problems.

Comment: just add scrollview tag

Comment: adding ScrollView tag would show just one row in GridView as well as ListView.

Comment: please provide me with some code @DanielJulio

Comment: @DivyamGarg The method I stated works well if you don't have many list and grid items. How many do you have? If you have many you will need a different way because the rows won't be recycled.

Comment: @DanielJulio I have a 3x3 gridView and 4-5 items in a listView

Comment: @DivyamGarg I'm not going to get an example of this, but if I was you I would use a ScrollView with a LinearLayout (this would be your listview) and a TableLayout (for the gridview). Then you would loop through how many rows you have and inflate your row layout. Something like this to inflate the row: `LinearLayout mLl = (LinearLayout) inflate(context, R.layout.row, this);`. After this you simply add your row to LinearLayout or TableLayout using `linearLayout.addView(mLl);`

Answer (score 0):

Add a ScrollView to your xml file that will contain your list view and other elements you would like to scroll. ScrollView can only hold one child view. In order to make the whole screen scrollable, you have to put a single layout inside the ScrollView that contains all of your other views. LinearLayout, GridLayout, RelativeLayout can all hold multiple child views(nest your layouts and views in a single parent layout). Just make the ScrollView the height and width of the entire screen and you will have it.

Comment: Your answer should be edited, the use hasn't implemented any scrollview to make the height and width match the entire screen. Instead of editing you can suggest him to create a new scrollview.

Answer (score 0):

In such a case you just have to add a **`ScrollView`** like this :

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content">
.
.
.
</ScrollView>
```

But do remember to **remove** `xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"`, these two lines from your **LinearLayout**

Comment: Doing this would just show one row in GridView and ListView. How should i handle that?

Comment: So @DivyamGarg ... for that....
Is it really necessary to implement both grid and list in the same activity... 
Let me know what exactly you are planning to do?

Comment: I am trying to create an activity which has gridView items on the top, then a textview and then a list of items in a listView. The views are populated in the java file.

Comment: For such a thing, I would suggest you to fix the size of **ListView**  at the bottom and at top fix the size of **GridView** at top and in-between put your **TextView**; without putting any scollView

Answer (score 0):

```
        <ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"        
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"             
        tools:context=".MainActivity" >

        <LinearLayout 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        >

        <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <GridView
            android:id="@+id/grid"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:columnWidth="100dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:horizontalSpacing="2dp"
            android:numColumns="auto_fit"
            android:paddingTop="2dp"
            android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
            android:verticalSpacing="2dp" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:text="More Devices"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

        <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingBottom="3dp"
        android:paddingLeft="3dp"
        android:paddingTop="3dp" />

        </LinearLayout>
          </ScrollView>
```

Comment: Doing this would show only one row in gridView and listView. Please help @Azim Ansari

Answer (score 0):

You Should Put your Layout and Views Inside ScrollView

```
<LinearLayout>

    <ScrollView>

        <LinearLayout>
                  <GridView></GridView>
         </LinearLayout>
         <TextView></TextView>
         <LinearLayout>
                  <ListView></ListView>
         </LinearLayout>


    </ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Reference :[How can I put a ListView into a ScrollView without it collapsing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3495890/how-can-i-put-a-listview-into-a-scrollview-without-it-collapsing)

Comment: But ScrollView can have only one immediate child and not more than that. @Anil Meenugu

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same problem as you. My line of solving the problem started with what the user Touhid points out [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13679633/how-to-make-android-listview-scrollable):

> Putting ListView inside a ScrollView is never inspired. But if you
>   want your posted XML-like behavior, there're 3 options to me:
>
> 1. Remove ScrollView: Removing your ScrollView, you may give the ListViews some specific size with respect to the total layout (either
>      specific dp or layout_weight).
> 2. Replace ListViews with LinearLayouts: You may add the list-items by iterating through the item-list and add each item-view to the
>      respective LinearLayout by inflating the view & setting the respective
>      data (string, image etc.)
> 3. If you really need to put your ListViews inside the ScrollView, you must make your ListViews non-scrollable (Which is practically the same
>      as the solution 2 above, but with ListView codes), otherwise the
>      layout won't function as you expect.  To make a ListView
>      non-scrollable, you may read this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7611085/disable-scrolling-in-listview), where the precise
>      solution to me is like the one below

:

In my case:

1. solution 1 - remove ScrollView - was not an option. Creating
   ListViews with specific sizes was just bad looking and confusing.
2. I wanted to try to *Replace ListViews with LinearLayouts*, but it turns out the [first hit on google](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32067358/how-to-change-my-listview-to-linearlayout-in-android) searching this suggested: *it's not good idea, specially if your ListView contains a lot of items. It's better to add header to your ListView or use custom NonScrollableListView class*. As headers looked bad also on my lists, I decided not to.
3. So it seems the last option was for me. I did make my ListViews non scrollable. And it worked great. The answer I found was [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18813296/non-scrollable-listview-inside-scrollview). More precisely the answer by Dedaniya HirenKumar - answered Jul 8 '14 at 10:21. 
   Be careful not to forget the last part of that answer. It is not enough to create the nonscrollable listview java class and to change the XML!!! You need to define your nonscrollable listviews in your Java file linked to the xml. Also be careful that you place the nonscrollable listview javaclass inside your package.