# How to change my ListView to LinearLayout in Android?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview, android-linearlayout

I am building an Android application where I am fetching data from a local DB and displaying it in a custom `ListView`.

Now the problem is I want to use `LinearLayout` in place of `ListView` as a scroll problem.

Below my code that I am using for `listView`.

1. Declaration in activity -

   ```
   lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);

   adapter = new CustomAdapter(this, dbh.fetchAllRec(),
           CursorAdapter.NO_SELECTION);
   lv.setAdapter(adapter);
   ```
2. CustomListView -

   ```
   public class CustomAdapter extends CursorAdapter {

   ///---  cunstructor ---///

   @Override
   public void bindView(View v, Context context, Cursor c) {
   // TODO Auto-generated method stub
   //TextView tvId=(TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.tvId);

   //tvId.setText(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(c.getColumnName(0))));
   //tvId.setText(c.getString(arg0));

   TextView tvEmail = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.tvEmail);
   tvEmail.setText(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(c.getColumnName(4))));

   TextView tvPword = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.tvPword);
   tvPword.setText(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(c.getColumnName(5))));

   TextView tvMobile =(TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.tvMobile);
   String FlatNumber = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(c.getColumnName(1)));
   String Landmark = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(c.getColumnName(2)));
   String Address = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(c.getColumnName(3)));
   tvMobile.setText(FlatNumber+","+Landmark+","+Address);

     }

   @Override
     public View newView(Context context, Cursor c, ViewGroup parent ) {
       // TODO Auto-generated method stub
     LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
     View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.cust_list, parent, false);

     return v;
    }

   }
   ```

   ```
   <TextView
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:text="@string/locationT1"
       android:textSize="14sp" />

   <TextView
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
       android:text="@string/locationT2"
       android:textSize="10sp" />

   <RelativeLayout
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="40dp"
       android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_10"
       android:background="@drawable/cornerround">

       <ImageView
           android:id="@+id/mapLogo"
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:layout_centerVertical="true"
           android:contentDescription="@null"
           android:src="@drawable/locationicon" />

       <TextView
           android:id="@+id/pickerUserAddress"
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:layout_centerVertical="true"
           android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/margin_50"
           android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/mapLogo"
           android:lines="1"
           android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_14" />

       <ImageView
           android:id="@+id/editLocation"
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
           android:layout_centerVertical="true"
           android:contentDescription="@null"
           android:src="@drawable/editiconn" />
   </RelativeLayout>

   <EditText
       android:id="@+id/pickerUserName"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="40dp"
       android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_10"
       android:background="@drawable/cornerround"
       android:hint="@string/hintEnterName"
       android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_14" />

   <EditText
       android:id="@+id/pickerUserPhoneNumber"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="40dp"
       android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_10"
       android:background="@drawable/cornerround"
       android:hint="@string/hintEnterPhoneNumber"
       android:inputType="phone"
       android:maxLength="12"
       android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_14" />

   <EditText
       android:id="@+id/pickerUserFlaNumber"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="40dp"
       android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_10"
       android:background="@drawable/cornerround"
       android:hint="@string/hintFlatNumber"
       android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_14" />

   <EditText
       android:id="@+id/pickerLandMark"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="40dp"
       android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_10"
       android:background="@drawable/cornerround"
       android:hint="@string/hintLandmark"
       android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_14" />

   <RelativeLayout
       android:id="@+id/pickerCollectCash"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_10">

       <TextView
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
           android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
           android:layout_centerVertical="true"
           android:text="@string/cashToCollect" />

       <EditText
           android:id="@+id/pickerCashToCollect"
           android:layout_width="@dimen/width_100"
           android:layout_height="40dp"
           android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
           android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
           android:layout_gravity="end"
           android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_5"
           android:background="@drawable/cornerround"
           android:hint="@string/hintRs"
           android:inputType="phone"
           android:maxLength="5"
           android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_14" />

   </RelativeLayout>


   <RelativeLayout
       android:id="@+id/PickerDoneBtn"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="40dp"
       android:layout_gravity="right"
       android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
       android:background="@color/secondary_color">

       <TextView
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
           android:layout_centerVertical="true"
           android:paddingLeft="20dp"
           android:paddingRight="20dp"
           android:text="PROCEED" />

   </RelativeLayout>


   <RelativeLayout
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
       android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
       android:background="@color/newDesignGrey">

       <TextView
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
           android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
           android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
           android:text="Saved Addresses"
           android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_14"
           android:textStyle="bold" />
   </RelativeLayout>

   <ListView
       android:id="@+id/listView1"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:dividerHeight="0dp"
       android:scrollbars="none"
       android:background="@color/newDesignGrey" />
   ```

Comment: Explain your problem. I don't think that you should get rid of the listview.

Comment: @ThomasR. Actually There is many tool I am using above listview and I need when I scroll dowen listView should according to my page. full page should scroll rather then a listView

Comment: can show your xml file

Comment: Why do you need adater to set data in linear layout...

Comment: DON'T get rid of your listview in favor of linearlayout - it would be  very challenging to do besides.

Comment: @user5114910 I have added my xml to above question please check.

Answer (score 0):

Please, describe all scope of issue.

As I see from question and comments, you've got a ListView, which scrolls on some part of the screen, but you need to scroll all the screen. And you want to cast ListView to LinearLayout. Is that correct? If yes, it's not good idea, specially if your ListView contains a lot of items. It's better to add header to your ListView or use custom NonScrollableListView class. But as for me first option is preferable.

Waiting comments from you, it'll be a bit more clear for me after your response.

Comment: Yes You are right. change all the tool to the header will take a lot of time can you suggested something else

Comment: then you can also add the listview and whole other views in a scrollview.

Comment: It's not good practice to add ListView inside ScrollView. Basically, in that case you will have two scroll handlers on the screen and android won't know which to use. When I tried to perform such trick, I just received first item of my ListView, that's all. Actually, I don't see a problem in putting your views in some container, getting id of this container and making a header from it, but if such a problem might be, this topic may help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4338185/how-to-get-a-non-scrollable-listview See comments, there are a lot of solutions.

Comment: I dont think so and this could support my views..http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18813296/non-scrollable-listview-inside-scrollview

Comment: check 2nd answer of this link too http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6210895/listview-inside-scrollview-is-not-scrolling-on-android