# How to disable auto scrolling in ListView when new items added?

Tags: android, android-listview

I have application with ListView. This ListView scrolling when I adding new items. But I didn't need that. How to stop this? That only user can scroll it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you need to stop your ListView, Please override the dispatchTouchEvent()
 method intercepting the action that you want to get, only.

This was also explained here: 
[Disable scrolling in listview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7611085/disable-scrolling-in-listview)

Answer (score 0):

In CustomListView override this method and return false.

```
@Override 
public boolean requestChildRectangleOnScreen(View child, Rect rect, boolean immediate) {
   return false;
}
```