# LinearLayout not scrolling inside ScrollView

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-linearlayout, android-scrollview

I'm trying to figure out why this `LinearLayout` is not scrolling:

```
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

   <LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="2"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="35dp"
        android:text="TITLE 1"
        android:textSize="30sp" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="20sp" />

</LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

I'm adding programmatically a `textView` and a `listView` to the `linearLayout`, and the page is cut in half. The only things scrolling are the `listViews`.

I don't need the `listViews` to be scrollable, I only want the entire `linearLayout` scrollable.

Comment: Yes, as you can see I solved looking to that answer, no the accepted one but the second. Thanks however

Comment: Ok I mark as duplicate, the solution for me was the second answer of the other post.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
<androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

   <LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="2"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="35dp"
        android:text="TITLE 1"
        android:textSize="30sp" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="20sp" />

</LinearLayout>
</androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

Comment: Tried but it's not working ..

Comment: I updated my question with one more detail

Answer (score 0):

The listview doesn't scroll because it is nested.
If you use listview inside Scrollview, they might interrupt each other. (both scrolls)
You should customize your Scrollview, so the scrollview will be stop scrolling  when you touch listview area.

1) Create new class: `CustomScrollView` and extend it from `ScrollView`

2) Change your xml `<ScrollView>` to your custom scrollview: `<com.your_package_name.CustomScrollView>`

`CustomScrollView.java:`

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.widget.ScrollView;

public class CustomScrollView extends ScrollView {
    public CustomScrollView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public CustomScrollView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public CustomScrollView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
        final int action = ev.getAction();
        switch (action) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                //Log.i("CustomScrollView", "onInterceptTouchEvent: DOWN super false" );
                super.onTouchEvent(ev);
                break;

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                return false; // redirect MotionEvents to ourself

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:
                // Log.i("CustomScrollView", "onInterceptTouchEvent: CANCEL super false" );
                super.onTouchEvent(ev);
                break;

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                //Log.i("CustomScrollView", "onInterceptTouchEvent: UP super false" );
                return false;

            default:
                //Log.i("CustomScrollView", "onInterceptTouchEvent: " + action );
                break;
        }

        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
        super.onTouchEvent(ev);
        //Log.i("CustomScrollView", "onTouchEvent. action: " + ev.getAction() );
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried, but it's not scrolling... I copied your class and changed xml

Comment: I updated my question with one more detail

Comment: I understood you.
But you have only 2 view, how can you scroll it if you have nothing after listview?
You can one way: Disable the listView ->
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7611085/disable-scrolling-in-listview

Comment: As I wrote in the post: "I'm adding programmatically a textView and a listView to the linearLayout" ... I finally find a solution, I posted it as an answer.