# How to disable listview scroll on android app widget

Tags: android, android-appwidget

I create a list view on app widget but I want to make my list view not scrollable. How to achieve that since we have limited control on view component in app widget.

Comment: Take a look 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7611085/disable-scrolling-in-listview

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Disable scrolling in listview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7611085/disable-scrolling-in-listview)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure whether does it work in app widget or not, but you can try to set nested scrolling of your list view by using:

```
my_listView.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false)
```