# Statelist drawable style looks like older Android 2.2 style

Tags: android, listview, drawable, statelistdrawable

I'm essentially trying to implement a ListView-like thing that doesn't scroll. (Relevant: [How to get a non scrollable ListView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4338185/how-to-get-a-non-scrollable-listview) ). I have almost everything working, except the "on-click" animation.

My base widget for the list elements is a `LinearLayout`. I found this nice trick, to set the background drawable to a selectable element, and turn "clickable" on. It works fine, but the style seems to be old Android 2.2, with the orange gradient.

Relevant code:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/listViewRow"
    android:background="@android:drawable/list_selector_background"
    android:clickable="true"
    ... >
```

Adding,

```
    style="@style/AppTheme"
```

doesn't seem to help. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you use   android:background and style at the same time?

Comment: @Yahor10, I tried it with and without the style setting. My default app style just inherits from android:Theme.Light now, though.