# Scroll Bar in List View

Tags: java, android

Why is there a **Scroll Bar** in **List View** even when the data in displayed in it doesn't require scrolling?
here is my xml file

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
     android:background="@drawable/background"
     android:orientation="vertical" >

   <ListView
      android:id="@+id/listview"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:divider="@null"
      android:dividerHeight="0dip" />

   <TextView
      android:id="@+id/empty"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:gravity="center"
      android:text="@string/no_result_text"
      android:visibility="gone" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Comparing `getLastVisiblePosition()` with `getCount()` in a Runnable, you will get to know whether your list view will fit into the screen or not. Also check if the last visible row fits entirely on the screen or not.

```
ListView listView;
Runnable fitsOnScreen = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        int last = listView.getLastVisiblePosition();
        if(last == listView.getCount() - 1 && listView.getChildAt(last).getBottom() <= listView.getHeight()) {
           listView.setScrollContainer(false);
        }
        else {
            listView.setScrollContainer(true);
        }
    }
};
```

Finally in ListView's Handler: onCreate()

```
listView.post(fitsOnScreen);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by

```
listView.setScrollContainer(false);
```

for more please check

[How to get a non scrollable ListView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4338185/how-to-get-a-non-scrollable-listview)

Answer (score 0):

If you are not want to hide the scrollbar for ever. Then it will help you.
 Due to android:layout_height="match_parent"  on listView and TextView scrollbar appears.

```
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
     android:background="@drawable/background"
     android:orientation="vertical" >

     <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" // change 1
        android:divider="@null"
        android:dividerHeight="0dip" />

     <TextView
        android:id="@+id/empty"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" //change 2
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/no_result_text"
        android:visibility="gone" />

 </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

android:scrollbars="none"

Try putting the above line in your listview in xml.