# Could I make ListViews on same screen completely expanded and not scrollable?

Tags: android, android-listview

I currently have a relative layout that has:

Linear Layout (Header)

Linear Layout (Header 2)

ListView (scrollable, first ListView occupies top half of screen)

Linear Layout (custom divider between 2 ListViews)

ListView (scrollable, second ListView that occupies bottom half of screen)

However, I want the 2 ListViews to be completely expanded and unscrollable (essentially the same effect of having the first ListView, the linear layout in between and the last ListView feel like just one scrollable ListView for the entire screen). Is this possible?
Thanks!

Comment: Never ever do this !!! never... You can add different row types in `ListView`. Please search how to do it and use that approach to add `LinearLayout` in your `ListView` wherever you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**NOTE :- Using a ListView to make it not scroll is extremely expensive and goes against the whole purpose of ListView. You should NOT do this. Just use a LinearLayout instead.**

First of all, you need to put some effort into doing this. Then you ask a question here , put some code to show us your effort.

Secondly, a listview basic functionality is scrollable. If you dont want to scroll a listview, why even make one.

That being said, there is no need to use a listview at all.

Listview can be replaced with a linearlayout. The List Adapter Adapter instead of attaching the adapter with your listview, simply call the getView function of the adapter in a for loop on your data and add the retrieved views to your vertical linearlayout.

This approach is only recommended if you have a small number of items in your list.

You can do  this also :-

```
listView.setScrollContainer(false);
```

or :-

Use a LinearLayout or whatever layout you're using for your Activity and put it inside a ScrollView.

for more please check

[How to get a non scrollable ListView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4338185/how-to-get-a-non-scrollable-listview)

Comment: Noooo ... don't tell him how to do it :-\

Comment: @M-WaJeEh - Just told him the way to do it. I did not provide him the code.