# View for a list of items that don't scroll, and handle on item click events by the item position

Tags: android, android-view

Just like a `ListView` but instead it doesn't scroll. Its content is added programatically via an `ArrayAdapter`. Is there any view that can be used for this purpose?

PS: Not `LinearLayout`, since it doesn't get its content from an adapter (I want the observer pattern)

**Edit:** Let me explain a little bit more. Suppose you need a list of items, but the list itself is not scrollable, what is scrollable is the screen.

That being said, the list of items should show **ALL** items, not a limited amount based on a fixed height. The way to go is `LinearLayout` as it is both non-scrollable and shows all items within itself.

But there is a third requierement. You don't want to `add(View)` directly, but instead, you want something similar to an `ArrayAdapter` so that you have a control of the items and their position, so you can handle on item click events based on their position. As far as I know, this can't be done using a `LinearLayout`. So my question is, does any view exist for this purpose?

Comment: Have you tried `listView.setScrollContainer(false);` ?

Comment: Could you please elaborate more? I didn't understand.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get a non scrollable ListView?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4338185/how-to-get-a-non-scrollable-listview)

Answer (score 0):

You could try using a ListView, but disable scrolling, as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4338185/how-to-get-a-non-scrollable-listview)

Answer (score 0):

Put your layout inside a `ScrollView` and yes you have to use a `Linearlayout`. You need to set tag for each of your view that you add dynamically and whenever your view is clicked you can get it's position by `view.getTag()` and perform the required operation.

**Note : Adding views at run time may affect performance.**