# Android - Scrolling without a ScrollBar

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout, android-xml, android-relativelayout

I have the following layout (for brevity sake, I removed the different attributes):

```
<RelativeLayout>
    <LinearLayout>
        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar/>
        <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/item1"/>
        <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/item2"/>
        <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/item3"/>
        <ListView/>
    </LinearLayout>
    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

I am trying to get this whole page to be scrollable. At the moment, only the ListView scrolls. Any idea how to do? Note that I cannot use ScrollView due to the fact that I embed a ListView. Also, the outer element must be RelativeLayout as I need the FloatingActionButton to be fixed regardless of scrolling.

Comment: One direction I am considering: addHeaderView(View) in which I can add items 1,2.3. The toolbar can be fixed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Having a `ListView` inside a `ScrollView` would cause you a lots of trouble. Instead leave only the `ListView` in your layout

```
<RelativeLayout>
    <LinearLayout>
        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar/>
        <ListView/>
    </LinearLayout>
    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

and move your `LinearLayouts` into separate file (for example **header.xml**)

```
<LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/item1"/>
    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/item2"/>
    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/item3"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

You can then add the layout as header to your `ListView` with

```
ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
View header = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.header, listView, false);
listView.addHeaderView(header); // call before you set adapter!
```

Now the whole view will be scrollable. If you use `onItemClickListener` don't forget that the index is shifted by `listView.getHeaderViewsCount()`.

Comment: Perfect! Exactly what I was pursuing and you gave a very clear example! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Using a vertical scrollable inside vertical scrollable is always messy and might just not work, but you can chceck [LINK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4338185/how-to-get-a-non-scrollable-listview)

also you can use `listView.requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(false)`.

Answer (score -1):

I think that the only way to make a layout scrollable is to put all of the content into a `ScrollView` for example like this:

```
<RelativeLayout>
    <ScrollView android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <LinearLayout>
            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar/>
            <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/item1"/>
            <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/item2"/>
            <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/item3"/>
            <ListView/>
        </LinearLayout>
        <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton/>
    </ScrollView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: a ListView cannot be inside a ScrollView.

Comment: you can use listView inside of a scrollView if you copy the setListViewHeightBasedOnChildren(lv) method in your code and with this you could expand the listView. Another possible solution is to simplify your layout and to put the layouts you want to be scrolled too in the listVeiw as headers or footers