# Display 2 listviews with one being able to scroll

Tags: android, listview

I have 2 list views in a fragment stacked vertically. The top list has a fixed number of rows(it doesn't change). The second list is populated dynamically. My question is I want the first list to always be visible and the second to be able to scroll if it has many rows. I should say when the second list is scrolling, it SHOULD NOT scroll the first. It should only scroll its contents.

Comment: Did you try adding a `ScrollView` container around your second list?

Comment: @not_again_stackoverflow ListView doesn't work inside a ScrollView. WRAP_CONTENT shows only first item, don't do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the first list contents in some other layout (not ScrollView,ListView) ex.LinearLayout, So you can have only one scrollable list item that is the second one

Answer (score 0):

Apply this to the list view you don't want to scroll:

```
listView.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

        // If the user wants to scroll, override the default event
        if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE) {
            return true; // So the system doesn't handle the event
        }
        return false;
    }

});
```

The second list view should still be able to scroll.

Original Answer in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21630258/5609492)

Comment: The second list view isn't scrolling. And also the first list view(the one that should not scroll) is behaving weird, it is selecting list items(rows) that haven't been selected, if I attempt to scroll across it, it interprets that as list item selection.

Comment: Maybe it would be easier for you to replace the first list view with a linear layout, since it should not scroll

Comment: Yes, I think that is the proper method. But there are many rows in the first list(5 rows) that would be easier to populate by a list adapter than to manually create them in a vertical linear layout