# Multiple non-scrollable lists in a ScrollView in Android

Tags: android, list, scrollview, scrollable

I am trying to put multiple lists that don't need to be scrollable inside a `ScrollView`. In other words, I have a `TextView` as a header for a category, with a list under it. Then another `TextView` as another header, with another list under that. And so on. This is in a vertical `LinearLayout`.

I want to be able to scroll through this layout as it gets off the screen when it has too much info, but I want all the contents of the lists to be displayed.

I've tried putting the headers (the `TextViews`) and the lists inside a vertical `LinearLayout`, and that `LinearLayout` inside a `ScrollView`. The problem with that approach is - all the lists have a max vertical dimension of exactly one element (if I set them to "wrap content"), despite the lists having multiple elements. Believe it or not, the lists do scroll (and they're inside of a `ScrollView`, more exactly, inside of a `ScrollView` -> `LinearLayout`).

If I remove the `ScrollView`, then the lists do indeed appear with all their elements, but I can't scroll the view if it goes off the screen.

So, if I use a `ScrollView`, I only get one element per each list. If I don't use it, I get all the elements of the lists correctly, but it doesn't scroll.

Any ideas of solving this? Thanks!

Comment: ListView with custom adapter. Use index to inflate header and items from two different layouts as required.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind, eventually found the answer here and it works perfectly:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/27818748/5627584

This ^^^ is a very underrated answer as I have hardly found it, but it's very, very useful when trying to include lists inside of superior layout node that has to be scrollable (inside of a `ScrollView` -> `LinearLayout` that contains other interface elements).